# Rendering Markdown on Mac and Windows

Tags: windows, macos, visual-studio-code, markdown

I'm using VS Code on Windows. However, I noticed that the Markdown Preview can only render very few MathJax/Latex elements compared to a friend who has a Mac. For instance, my VS Code can't render $\ce{...}$ (when writing chemical equations). What is the cause? I tried to install VS Code extensions (Markdown+Math, Markdown Preview Enhanced...) to add it, but it doesn't work. What could I do to have the same possibilities?

Comment: How are you signalling to the Markdown processor that this is Latex?

Comment: I am just using dollars, if I understood the question correctly: for instance ```$\ce{2H2O + H2SO4 -> 2H3O+(aq) + SO4^2-(aq) }$```